# How to merge a for loop with an if-else statement?

Tags: python, generator-expression

I am trying to delete all the **first** element of a list that are equals among themselves, but I found my code ugly.

Here an example: `my_list = [1,1,1,9,9,2]` become `my_list = [1,9,9,2]`

```
for spot_prec, spot in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]):
    if spot_prec == spot:
        del spot_prec
    else:
        break
```

How to compact it? I heard about generator expression, but I have a problem to include my `else break` statement.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for `unique_justseen` found in the [`itertools` recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly - not sure why you're looping here...? And I don't think that code is doing what you think it is either...

Comment: Can you include example input and desired output?

Answer (score -1):

After clarification of OP, seems what is needed is something like:

```
for ii, element in enumerate(my_list):
    if element == my_list[0]:
       continue
    else:
       break
new_list = my_list[ii-1:]
```

Also, using itertools [dropwhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile), we can concatenate element 0 and the result of dropping any element at the beginning that is equal to the first element:

```
new_list = [my_list[0]] + list(dropwhile(lambda x: x == my_list[0], my_list))
```

Comment: I don't want to check only the first and second element, here an example : `my_list = [1,1,1,9,9,2]` become `my_list = [1,9,9,2]`

Comment: You can then do it in several ways, I have changed my answer to include a pair of examples, I prefer the first one, since it's more obvious.